# Android Emulator not Active

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

**UPDATE1**: added explanation of inactive.

I have a running android emulator running an app downloaded from apkpure.com. The keyboard typing is enabled in setting, and I can type ( e.g. in android browser). However, when I start the app, the emulator becomes inactive (the title bar is greyed out as shown in the picture), and I can no longer type (e.g. the password field):
[image: The title bar becomes grey when I start the app]

I would like to ask why this is happening and what I can do to be able to type. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by **emulator becomes inactive**?  this information is not enough and people may downvote or close or simply ignore your question.

Comment: Thanks Vic, I've added explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try your apk in other emulators like [genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) or in an actual device. If you think the app is running well in your mobile but not in the emulator just remove the emulator from your adv device and add a new one or make a new custom emulator based on your app requirement.

Comment: Thank you Sohel, I'll try to verify and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround.

When I click the More button at the end of the controls, a settings window pops up. Then I close the window, and I'm able to type in the password field (and the emulator window becomes active).

[image]